# Post Request with image encoding like data not like string

Tags: objective-c, post, encoding

sorry I am new on this.

I have make this to upload a image to a server. The problem is that the guy how has make the server are waiting for a jpg file, and I am sending a jpg encoding in a string. What can I do? All the examples that I have seen send it like in my code.

```
    static NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tarjetaPrueba.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0)];


    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"front\"; \r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:imageData];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Probably Base64 encoding is used. So search how to convert data to Base64 encoded String.

Comment: Hi, the man of the server said to me that they check if I send a JPG. Like I send a String (jpg encoded) its fail. I think It is going to be the same with Base64. They need a JPG file.